# DocuSign Rest API- Is there a way to configure three optional fields such that if one of them is filled the other two must also field

Tags: docusignapi

Hi I am using Docusign rest api. I have a scenario where I have three fields that needs to be filled by the same person(2 text and 1 signature all of them optional). Is there a way to make them such that if one of the text field is filled the signature must be required?

I am trying to use "conditionalParentLabel" and "conditionalParentValue" to achieve this fuctionality but I am not sure what value to give for "conditionalParentvalue" so that the required will get activated for all text input except blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample [CreateEnvelope](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/) call that could work for you.

> POST /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes

```
{
    "recipients": {
        "signers": [
            {
                "email": "janedoe@yourdomain.com",
                "name": "Jane Doe",
                "recipientId": 1,
                "tabs": {
                    "signHereTabs": [
                        {
                            "optional": "false",
                            "documentId": "1",
                            "pageNumber": "1",
                            "xPosition": "279",
                            "yPosition": "89",
                            "conditionalParentLabel": "Amount",
                            "conditionalParentValue": "##ANY##"
                        }
                    ],
                    "textTabs": [
                        {
                            "height": 11,
                            "width": 78,
                            "required": "false",
                            "locked": "false",
                            "maxLength": 100,
                            "tabLabel": "Amount",
                            "documentId": "1",
                            "pageNumber": "1",
                            "xPosition": "117",
                            "yPosition": "119"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "emailSubject": "Requesting signature with conditional fields",
    "documents": [
        {
            "documentId": "1",
            "name": "Doc One",
            "fileExtension": "txt",
            "documentBase64": "RG9jIFRXTyBUV08gVFdP"
        }
    ],
    "status": "sent"
}
```